# ionic running issue in windows

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am Getting below error while i am running the same....pls help

```
E:\App_testing\MyFirstApp>ionic serve
{ Error
    at new Exception (C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\errors.js:8:23)
    at new FatalException (C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\errors.js:17:9)
    at Config.<anonymous> (C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\config.js:61:35)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:101:69)
    at <anonymous> name: 'Exception', exitCode: 1, fatal: true }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to config.json file, delete the config.json file from location

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\.ionic\config.json
```